# Connection Property does not work in Azure ServiceBus Subscription-triggered Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#connections), you can specify a Connection in a ServiceBus-triggered function. The Connection should reference an App Setting by that name that contains a connection string to an Azure ServiceBus Namespace.

I have an App Setting containing a valid Azure ServiceBus connection string, and the `Connection` parameter is set to the setting name. However, the function does not fire. It does work locally, or if I use the default setting name "AzureWebJobsServiceBus." Obviously I don't want to use that name since I may have multiple connections.

App settings:
[image: App Settings]

Function code:

```
FunctionName("Test")]
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topicname", "subscriptionname", Connection = "AzureWebJobsTestConn", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]
```

I've also tried:

```
FunctionName("Test")]
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topicname", "subscriptionname", Connection = "TestConn", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]
```

I've seen some related questions, but the answer generally given is to make sure to use Application Settings, not some config file - which I am.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue through the following steps:

1. Firstly, I have created a ***Service Bus*** namespae and a ***queue*** through Azure Portal.

[image]

2. Created the ***Azure functions*** project with Http Trigger template and authorization level as anonymous.
   Also I renamed my function file from `function1.cs` to `SendMessage.cs`
   And replaced the code to link service bus queue to note the number of messages read in the request passed.

[image]

**Code:**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace KrishSBFuncApp1
{
     public static class SendMessage
        {
            [FunctionName("SendMessage")]
            [return: ServiceBus("krishqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")]
            public static async Task<string> Run(
                [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
                ILogger log)
            {
                log.LogInformation("SendMessage function requested");
                string body = string.Empty;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    log.LogInformation($"Message body : {body}");
                }
                log.LogInformation($"SendMessage processed.");
                return body;
                    }
                }
           }    }
```

3. In the ***local.settings.json file***, copy your service bus namespace shared access policy primary connection string in any string ( here I named it as `"AzureWebJobsServiceBus":<rootmanagesharedaccesskey-conn-string>`)
   [image]
4. I have added same connection string to ***azure function app configuration*** settings as well like below:
   [image]

**Local Test using Postman:**
Build and Run the application in Visual studio > You'll get an API.
Copy that API URL to the postman and enter the body.
[image]
[image]

#### Test using Azure Functions URL after deploying/publishing your function app to azure:

1. Azure Portal > Function App > Click on Functions (in the left index pane) > Select Your Function > Click on Code+Test (in the left index pane).
2. You can run the application through Test/Run option or in postman also.
3. I executed in both ways as you see below image which differentiates you to understand which output belongs to which output.

I have given body as `Hello Dear Krishna` and send the request in ***postman*** and another time I have executed through **Test/Run** option in the azure portal by giving body as `Hello Krishna`.

[image]

***And the Queue count is:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed analysis! This is not relevant to my problem for 2 reasons: 1. I am implementing a ServiceBus-triggered function that is supposed to get triggered by messages placed on a queue - not a function that enqueues messages, 2. The entire problem occurs when using an app setting with a different name than "AzureWebJobsServiceBus"

Comment: I have given the information how to configure AzureWebJobsServiceBus in both function code as well as in the azure function app (portal). Please check once.

Comment: I thought you're using service bus connection to be triggered by messages. If you need the solution while using ServiceBusTrigger, I'll try to resolve and provide that information.